# d-separation in this graph

Tags: graph-theory

I have the following graph [image]

My question is, is 0 and 2 d-separated given 1?

We have the path 2-1-0, which is clearly blocked by 1. Then we have the path 2-3-1-0, which has a v-structure on 1. So on one hand 1 blocks a path, but at the same time the v-structure does not allow 1 to be in the separating set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, 0 and 2 are not d-separated given 1.

Recall that 0 and 2 will be d-separated if there is no active path from 0 to 2. And a path is active only if all triples of random variables along the path are active.

From 0 to 2, there are two possible paths:

Path a: 0 -> **1** -> 2 (where 1 is observed). This triple is inactive (causal chain with the middle node observed) and, hence, the path is inactive.

Path b: 0 -> **1** <- 3 -> 2 (where 1 is observed). The triple 0 -> **1** <- 3 is active (it is a V-structure with the middle node 1 observed). Moreover, **1** <- 3 -> 2 is also active (common cause with the middle 3 node unobserved). Therefore, this path is active.

Since there is one active path from 0 to 2 (given 1), they are not d-separated and we cannot guarantee independence of 0 and 2 given 1.

Hope the answer helps